# is there a warning (error), similar to C4061 for C#

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement, compile-time

Usually, if I use switch for enums in C#, I have to write something like that:

```
switch (e)
{
    case E.Value1:
        //...
        break;

    case E.Value2:
        //...
        break;

        //...
    default:
        throw new NotImplementedException("...");
}
```

In C++ (for VS) I could enable warnings C4061 and C4062 for this switch, make them errors and have a compile-time check. In C# I have to move this check to runtime...

Does anyone know how in C# I can have this checked in compile time? Maybe there is a warning, disabled by default, which I missed, or some other way?

Comment: Please explain the warnings for those not familiar with the C++ Cxyz-warnings.

Comment: they are explained in msdn quite well. In a few words, in C++ code if you enable them, use "switch" for some enumeration, and forget to process some of the enumeration values (in separate "case") you will receive a warning during compilation

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't be a compile-time check - it's legitimate to have a switch/case which only handles some of the named values. It would have been *possible* to include it, but there are some issues.

Firstly, it's entirely valid (unfortunately) for an enum value not to have any of the "named" values:

```
enum Foo
{
    Bar = 0,
    Baz = 1
}
...
Foo nastyValue = (Foo) 50;
```

Given that *any* value is feasible within the switch/case, the compiler can't know that you didn't mean to try to handle an unnamed value.

Secondly, it wouldn't work well with `Flags` enums - the compiler doesn't really know which values are meant to be convenient combinations. It *could* infer that, but it would be a bit icky.

Thirdly, it's not always what you want - sometimes you really do only want to respond to a few cases. I wouldn't want to have to suppress warnings on a reasonably regular basis.

You can use [`Enum.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) to check for this up front, but that's relatively inefficient.

I agree that all of this is a bit of a pain - enums are a bit of a nasty area when it comes to .NET :(

Comment: thank you. But I disagree with "No, there can't be a compile-time check.". In C++ you can set any value to enum too, but there is an opportunity to check, that you processing all expected values.

Comment: maybe you know about some 3rdparty tool (like StyleCop) which can check this?

Comment: @Alek86: I don't, I'm afraid. (That doesn't mean they don't exist, only that I've never knowingly seen or used such a feature.) With Roslyn you could probably write your own, mind you :)

Comment: A good part of this answer leans to the "handle enum values not explicitly declared". However OP's question is more about "failing to handle not explicitly declared values". (Indeed flag-enums are different, and it's nice that C# can at least separate them a bit.)

Comment: Re: "only want to respond to a few cases"... Certainly, but one should consider future changes to the enum. When one new value is added, the default handling may be incorrect. A compiler warning/error helps here, similar to new/override keywords for members.

Comment: @PabloH: Well there certainly *isn't* anything in C# that will do this for you, and I don't anticipate any language change here in the future. (Switch expressions will warn you if they're not exhaustive, but that's just a matter of providing a default behavior.)

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this is necroposting, but nothing really changed in this area inside of the compiler. So, I made Roslyn analyzer for switch statements. 
You can download [SwitchAnalyzer package.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SwitchAnalyzer)
This is Roslyn analyzer and it supports

- Enums with operations | and & for them. So, you can check flags as well
  (but not like single int value)
- Interface implementations (pattern matching) in the current data context.

Pattern matching for classes is not implemented in version 0.4 yet (but I hope to implement it soon).
To use it, just add this package to your project, you will get warnings for all uncovered cases *if you don't have **default** branch or if it throws exception*. And of course, you can enable "Treat warnings as errors" option for your project for all or specific warnings. Feel free to contact me in case if you will find any bugs.